# I have installed flutter by snap ubuntu and then when I run flutter in terminal this error happens

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
[.releases[] | select(.hash==)][0].archive
jq: 1 compile error
Downloading /
curl: (3)  malformed
tar: latest_stable.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Flutter initialization failed
Could not find working copy of Flutter

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I live in Iran and I have changed my IP and it worked

Comment: but I still have this problem after using vpn. I think it's because "jq: 1 compile error"